# What are important difference between WebViews and browsers?

Tags: android, ios, webview, android-camera

I had a little trouble finding updated information about WebViews, and as a back-end developer, I would like to understand how they work and differ from the actual WebKit browser engine?

For practical purposes, I'm interested in the experience that happens by default for users when they scan a QR code using their native camera. I would like this to navigate to my website. The user would sign in, and I want to give them a cookie or session id to provide them with authentication.

As I understand, when a user scans a code with their camera, clicking on a link, the link is opened in a WebView, rather than their preferred browser. If the user closes the WebView after they sign in, such as by navigating back into their camera's functionality, the stored cookies will be lost.

Would appreciate references to the specific behavior and technical details of the webpage and storage information from browser pages opened from cameras on both iOS and Android.

Comment: When you can a QR code with a link it depends on the QR code app where the URL is opened. I would expect that most apps open the link in the main web browser and not in a WebView in the QR code app. Note that WebViews aren't directly usable by Android users, they can only be used by apps.

Comment: "when a user scans a code with their camera, clicking on a link, the link is opened in a WebView, rather than their preferred browser" -- what camera apps do with the results of scanned QR codes depends on the camera app. There are hundreds of camera apps and dedicated barcode scanning apps, both pre-installed and user-installed. "If the user closes the WebView after they sign in, such as by navigating back into their camera's functionality, the stored cookies will be lost." -- cookie storage rules are tied to the app using the `WebView`.

Comment: "*when they scan a QR code using their native camera*" if by "native" you meant "stock/built-in", just a note that not *all* built-in camera apps on Android devices are able to scan QR codes in the first place, especially on older devices. They have to resort to 3rd-party apps.